# Validation Introduction breaks script

Tags: php, validation

Using the following script to send info to a flatfile and it works until the introduction of the validation. Getting a Parse error at the brace { on line 23.
**What is the likely cause of the breakage ?**

```
<?php
    // we must never forget to start the session
    session_start();
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Form to Flat File</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $vname = $_GET["visitor"];
    $vemail = $_GET["visitormail"];
    $vphone = $_GET["visitorphone"];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $httpref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $httpagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;

    // VALIDATION INTRODUCTION - THESE ARE THE FORM FIELDS THAT WE REQUIRED THE VISITOR TO FILL IN  
        if(empty($vname) 
        || empty($vemail) 
        || empty($vphone) 
        {      //Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\Poll\DRBPoll\RaffleInfo.php on line 23
        echo "<h2>Go Back and fill in all fields  </h2>\n";
        echo '<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)"><h3>Go Back to the Raffle Form</h3></a><br />';    /*GO BACK BUTTON*/
        die ("Use the Go Back to Raffle Form button !! ");
        }
        if(!$vemail == "" && (!strstr($vemail,"@") || !strstr($vemail,"."))) 
        {
        echo "<h2>Go Back and enter a valid E-mail Address</h2>\n";
        echo '<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)"><h3>Go Back to the Raffle Form</h3></a><br />';    /*GO BACK BUTTON*/
        die ("Use the Go Back to Raffle Form button !!");   
        }

    // THANK YOU MESSAGE IS WORKING

    print("<b>Thank You!</b><br />Your information will be entered once into the raffle!");
    $out = fopen("savedinfo.php", "a");
    if (!$out) {
    print("Could not add detail to Raffle file! Please contact the Webmaster");
    exit;
    }
    //OUTPUTS TO THE FLATFILE IS WORKING
    fputs ($out, "\n");
    fwrite($out,"$todayis [IST], $vname, $vemail, $vphone, $ip, $httpref, $httpagent.");
    fclose($out);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close the parenthesis you opened next to `if`.

Replace:

```
    if(empty($vname)
    || empty($vemail)
    || empty($vphone)
```

with:

```
    if(empty($vname)
    || empty($vemail)
    || empty($vphone))
```